# App crashing while calling httpClient.execute in Android for slow networks

Tags: java, android, http

i was using this method for checking the network status:

```
public boolean hasConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) SigninActivity.this
            .getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then calling the for web service for json by using this class:

```
    public class JSONParser {

InputStream is = null;
JSONObject jObj = null;
String json = "";
HttpClient httpClient;

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try { // defaultHttpClient DefaultHttpClient
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
    }
```

But the app is crashing for very slow networks were as works great in normal conditions.Can any one suggest better way to avoid force close?

"I was calling this class from AsyncTask class doInBackground method.
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: what is the stack-trace? why does it force-close?

Comment: Where you call this json parser class.

Comment: make sure your code is run outside the UI thread

Comment: when u call http resquest u should use thread or asynctask

Comment: Better you call json parse class inside the asynctask in main class.

Comment: @Steevo,@yugesh  i was calling this class from AsyncTask class doInBackground method. Question itself states it works fine in normal conditions.But wont work in slow networks.

Comment: Can you post the stack-strace?

Comment: Can you Post the log-cat details?

Comment: I am unable to post since its not crashing most of the times,But it shows "somehost.com UnknowHost"... It crashes only for the slow networks.

Comment: Atleast i was looking to hide the forceclose..